# Não grava no banco de dados e no console aparece como gravado

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa

Tenho um formulário dentro do modal para gravar cadastro, quando insiro os dados dá como se estivesse gravado no console do Eclipse, porém o mesmo não acontece no banco

Mensagem no console como Ok da gravação.

```
Hibernate: 
select
    empresa0_.id as id1_0_,
    empresa0_.cnpj as cnpj2_0_,
    empresa0_.data_fundacao as data_fun3_0_,
    empresa0_.nome_fantasia as nome_fan4_0_,
    empresa0_.razao_social as razao_so5_0_,
    empresa0_.tipo as tipo6_0_ 
from
    Empresa empresa0_


<p:commandButton id="salvar-button" value="Salvar" 
                    action="#{gestaoEmpresasBean.salvar}"
                    process="empresa-dialog" update="empresa-table"
                    oncomplete="PF('edicaoEmpresaDialog').hide()" />

@Inject
private Empresas empresas;

@Inject
private CadastroEmpresaService cadastroEmpresa;

@Inject
private FacesMessages messages;

private List<Empresa> todasEmpresas;
private Empresa empresaEdicao = new Empresa();

public void prepararNovoCadastro() {
    empresaEdicao = new Empresa();
}

public void salvar() {
    cadastroEmpresa.salvar(empresaEdicao);
    consultar();

    messages.info("Empresa salva com sucesso!");
}

public void consultar() {
    todasEmpresas = empresas.todas();
}

public List<Empresa> getTodasEmpresas() {
    return todasEmpresas;
}

public TipoEmpresa[] getTiposEmpresas() {
    return TipoEmpresa.values();
}

public Empresa getEmpresaEdicao() {
    return empresaEdicao;
}

public void setEmpresaEdicao(Empresa empresaEdicao) {
    this.empresaEdicao = empresaEdicao;
}
```

Service

```
@Transactional
public void salvar(Empresa empresa) {
    empresas.guardar(empresa);
}
```

Comment: Está dando *commit* após inserir, alterar e deletar as informações do banco? Até onde sei o *auto commit* é `false`.

Comment: Este log só mostra que o registro foi obtido do banco de dados, não mostra que foi persistido. Que tal você mostrar o código do bean (*gestaoEmpresasBean.salvar*)?

Comment: Esse erro abaixo seria do messages.properties no lugar errado?
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.algaworks.erp.Messages, locale pt_BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver, era erro de configuração do messages.properties que estava na pasta errada, faltou também o persistence.xml dentro da pasta META-INF embora eu já tinha criado automático pelo eclipse, fiz manual e deu certo. Abraço.